# Raw tcp connection in phoenix framework

Tags: tcp, phoenix-framework

I am an absolute new beginner in elixir/phoenix framework. Though I have got to know about channel(websocket) feature, I also require server handling(controller etc) of raw tcp connection. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are vague, thus necessitating a rather vague answer, but I will do my best.  Check out:

- http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html
- http://learnyousomeerlang.com/buckets-of-sockets
- https://excasts.com/episodes/a-connection-acceptor

The ExCasts episode is about `:gen_udp`, but the API is very close to `:gen_tcp` thus giving you an idea of how the API works.